# Randomly select Entites from database table?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

How would I randomly select rows from a database table? I'm using JPA and would like to use the Criteria API if possible. I'm aware there is an SQL equivalent, something like:

```
    SELECT TOP 5 Id, Name FROM mNames
    ORDER BY NEWID()
```

But how would I do this with JPQL and the Criteria API?
Possibly, with a NativeQuery? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a single random row, then you can do something like this:

```
//random is instance of java's Random class, and numberOfRows is total number of rows in the table
long rowIndex = random.nextLong()%numberOfRows;

TypedQuery typedQuery = ...;
typedQuery.setFirstResult(rowIndex);
typedQuery.setMaxResults(1);
```

I didn't test the code but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key of your entity is not an arbitrary number, but something functional, you might be better off, creating a valid key randomly and then querying the specific row, which is fast operation, instead of executing a possibly large number of rows just to filter out everything but one.